# Add javascript function dynamically inside script tag

Tags: javascript

Below function needs to be added dynamically inside a script tag which is also generated dynamically.

```
var targetFunction=function(){
            var sOut='<?xml version="1.0"?>\n';
            sOut+='<Logon username="" password="" appversion="1.0">\n';
            sOut+='\n</Logon>'
            document.getElementById("KXML").value=sOut;
            console.log(document.getElementById("KXML").value);
            var httpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
            httpReq.open("POST", 'http://my-url', true);
            httpReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/xml");
            httpReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
            httpReq.setRequestHeader('X-REST-API', true);
            httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {        
               if (httpReq.readyState == 4 && httpReq.status == 200) { 
                    document.getElementById('upload_target').innerHTML="";
                    var serverResponse = httpReq.responseText; 
                    document.getElementById("upload_target").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML=httpReq.responseText;;
                }
            }
            httpReq.send(document.getElementById("XML").value);      
        }
```

This function will be added in an iframe dynamically. To do this I need it to convert it into string.

I tried converting it to string by

```
alert(eval(targetFunction.toString()));
```

I was not able to do so.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the String() function?

See more here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp

Edit:

Have you tried removing the eval?

`alert(targetFunction.toString());`